# counter for instagram bot

Tags: selenium, count, instagram, bots

I made an instagram bot. When the program runs I want the instabot to count the posts.deployed to window seven and i made it with python

This is what I have written so far:

---

```
for i in range(1,2):
    try: 
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
        time.sleep(2)
        hrefss=driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
        hrefs = [elem.get_attribute('href') for elem in hrefss if '.com/p/' in elem.get_attribute('href')]
        time.sleep(2)
    except Exception:
        continue

    for href in hrefs:
        driver.get(href)
        try:            
            driver.find_element_by_class_name('_8-yf5 ').click()
```

Comment: edit content for clarity

Comment: to make it easier to format your code checkout the link with the markdown information in it. you can use 3 back ticks ``` to open a code block and ``` to close. this makes it easier to do spacing especially with python.